# How to filter ELB logs by today's date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT request_timestamp
FROM elb_logs
WHERE date_trunc('day', request_timestamp) = date_trunc('day', current_timestamp)
LIMIT 10
```

but it fails with:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:7: Unexpected parameters (varchar(3), varchar) for function date_trunc. Expected: date_trunc(varchar(x), date) , date_trunc(varchar(x), time) , date_trunc(varchar(x), time with time zone) , date_trunc(varchar(x), timestamp) , date_trunc(varchar(x), timestamp with time zone)

I've checked the [Date and Time Functions and Operators](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html) docs page, but I can't see anything wrong.

I've created the `elb_logs` table in Amazon Athena according to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/elasticloadbalancer-classic-logs.html#create-elb-table).

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `request_timestamp` needs to be converted from the ISO 8601 formatted string into a timestamp with time zone, or `current_timestamp` needs to be converted into the string.

One method is to convert `request_timestamp` into a string in format `%Y-%m-%d`, e.g.

- `split_part(request_timestamp, 'T', 1)`
- `substr(request_timestamp, 1, 10)`

then compare it with `current_timestamp` which can be converted to the ISO 8601 formatted string.

Here is the final query:

```
SELECT *
FROM elb_logs
WHERE split_part(request_timestamp, 'T', 1) = split_part(to_iso8601(current_timestamp), 'T', 1)
LIMIT 10
```